# Drupal 8: Theme's css and js files are not being loaded

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, drupal-8

I was trying to create a theme for Drupal 8.1.8. My CSS and JS files unfortunately cannot be loaded. I have checked if I used any tab characters, but I have used always 2 space characters for an indent.

I have read the documentation page at Drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets. I was trying around 2 hours with all possible combination. Also I tried the google search, Drupal core code inspection.. I could not figure it out.

My theme is located at **themes/englishtrainer**. The css is located in **themes/englishtrainer/css** and the javascript files are in **themes/englishtrainer/js**. The theme can be enabled as a theme without problems.

The contents of my theme's files in the following.

**englishtrainer.info.yml:**

```
name: Englishtrainer
type: theme
core: 8.x
version: '1.0.0'
libraries:
  - englishtrainer/base
regions:
  content: Content
  header: Header
```

**englishtrainer.libraries.yml:**

```
base:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      css/css-test.css: {}
  js:
    js/js-test.js: {}
```

**css/css-test.css:**

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**js/js-test.js:**

```
alert('it is loaded!');
```

I was checking the html markup for any occurrences. The javascript console has been also checked. It does not contain any entries. I have cleared the entire Drupal cache and disabled/enabled the theme. Nothing helped.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. My issue was, that I had a theme "and" a module with the same name. However the module did not implement any theming components. But this broke the theme. After I have uninstalled the module with the same name, the background was red (css worked) and the javascript alert appeared (javascript worked).

Thank you for your attention.